# Submenu opens in wrong hover area

Tags: html, css

Here is the [testing site](http://kuki.im/tootoo/). If you put your mouse on top left of the slider the submenu opens. I want it to open when I hover the menu button and not from the unrelated area. It's been hours that i'm trying but with no success. Here is the [link of the CSS](http://kuki.im/tootoo/css/style.css). I don't even know where the problem is located in the code. Thank you!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I'm so sorry! As i told in my topic i didn't have any idea where the problem was and i didn't want to add the whole css code here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dropdown is child of parent li... and since dropdown is displayed (with opacity 0), hover event gets fired from dropdown to parent and the styles apply.

Use display instead of opacity:

```
#menu .menu-dropdown {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #0099ff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 620px;

    /*opacity: 0;*/
    display:none;

    z-index: 9999;
}
#menu li:hover .menu-dropdown {
    left: 0;

    /*opacity: 1;*/
    display:block;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: It worked! So simple huh? Hours and hours of trying! Thank you!